# react js counting $ amount in local storage

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to count the $ amount of all the id's stored in local storage in react js.. any help is appreciated..

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';
import { carReducer } from '../reducers/CarReducers';

export const CarContext = createContext();

const CarContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [car, dispatch] = useReducer(carReducer, [], () => {
        const localData = localStorage.getItem('car');
        return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('car', JSON.stringify(car))
    }, [car])

    return (
        <CarContext.Provider value={{car, dispatch}}>
            {props.children}
        </CarContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default CarContextProvider
```

Comment: Please provide more clarity of what you have done so far, currently it is unclear what you have tries, what are the "car" objects you store in locaStorage, what exact problem you have and so on

Comment: I am trying to add all the prices together and display it. Right now its only displaying all individual prices, like the total amount in stock and its value. but i want everything to be displayed as one number added together

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Col, Container, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { CarContext } from '../contexts/CarContext';
 

const CarDetails = ({car}) => {
    const {dispatch} = useContext(CarContext);

    const totalprice = car.stock * car.price 

    const totalPrice = car.price

    return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <div className='box'>
                        {totalprice}
                </div>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                        <li onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'REMOVE_CAR', id: car.id})}>
                        <div className="title">
                            Car Make :   {car.make}
                        </div>
                        <div className='author'>
                            Car Modal :  {car.model}
                        </div>
                        <div className='author'>
                            Car ID :   {car.id}
                        </div>
                        <div className='author'>
                            Car Year  :  {car.year}
                        </div>
                        <div className='author'>
                        Car type :  {car.type}
                        </div>
                        <div className='author'>
                            Stock : {car.stock}
                        </div>
                        <div className='author'>
                            Car Price :  {totalPrice}
                        </div>
                    </li>     
                </Col>
            </Row>
           
        </Container>
    )
}

export default CarDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

and iam trying to display this in the navbar

```
const Navbar = () => {
    const {car} = useContext(CarContext);

    const totalprice = car.price * car.length


    return(
        <div className='navbar'>
            <h1>
                Car Inventory Management System
            </h1>
            <p>Currently you have {car.length} cars in the inventory.</p>
            <p>Total:  {totalprice} </p>
        </div>
    )

}
```